# Remove Size images without use

Tags: images

If possible know that size image are not used in my theme?

Example: If use a theme that have 10 size. But I think that I don´t use all images size.

Is possible know that size I don´t use?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just search for a specific image size within the theme files. The text editors like Atom, BBEdit, Notepad++ allows to do that.

P.S. You can find image size name in `add_image_size()` function argument.